# Exact code to load POI from local resource wikitude

Tags: wikitude

As i am using folllowing code to load POI fro local

```js
requestDataFromLocal: function requestDataFromLocalFn(lat, lon) {

  var poisNearby = Helper.bringPlacesToUser(myJsonData, lat, lon);
  World.loadPoisFromJsonData(poisNearby);

  /*
  For demo purpose they are relocated randomly around the user using a 'Helper'-function.
  Comment out previous 2 lines and use the following line > instead < to use static values 1:1.
  */

  //World.loadPoisFromJsonData(myJsonData); This line show only one POI

 }

};
```

And I am also seeking help to reload POI from local

Answer (score 0):

Use callCavaScript to pass information to JS environment and urlListener (document.location = "architectsdk://") to pass information to native code.

Have a look at these samples for more Information

- Retrieving POI Data [from Application Model](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/retrievingpoidata.html#applicationmodel)
- Native [POI Detail Page](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/browsingpois.html#nativedetailscreen)

Best regards

Comment: I had used the same code provided on documentation to load POI but that code shows only one POI

Comment: And can you please provide me code to navigate into another custom activity while pressing more button. And I am confused on provided code at documentation